# WebClient security error when accessing the world of warcraft armoury

Tags: c#, silverlight, security, world-of-warcraft

I am trying to piece together a solution to a problem.
Basically I am using Silverlight 4 with C# 4.0 to access the world of warcraft armoury.
If anyone has done this - please oh please provide the working .net 4.0 code.

The code I am attempting to run is (e.Error contains a securtiy error):

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string url = @"http://eu.wowarmory.com/guild-info.xml?r=Eonar&n=Gifted and Talented"; 
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();

            // HOW DO I ADD A USER AGENT STRING (RESPONSE MAY VARY (I.E. HTML VS XML) IF PAGE THINKS CALL IS NOT CAPABABLE OF SUPPORTING XML TRANSFORMATIONS) 
            //wc.ResponseHeaders["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)";

            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));    
        }

        void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                string result = e.Result;

                XDocument ArmouryXML = XDocument.Parse(result);

                ShowGuildies(ArmouryXML);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Something is complaining about security but not sure what!");
            }
        }
```

**Notes:**

1. C# 4.0
2. The armoury is an XML file - but i believe it reverts to html should the request not be from a browser that supports XML transformation.  But i don't think I am getting this far.
3. The armoury has a cross domain policy file on it - this may be the cause of the error (not sure!
4. I have uploaded to a production server
5. I am testing it locally using IIS website
6. I am going insane!
7. Websites have made the suggestion that this problem can be overcome by creating a WebProxy - but I haven't the first clue how to do this.

*It would be great if someone could take on this challenge and show us all that it is possible.  I'd prefer a non-proxy solution first, then try a proxy.*

**The error details:**

e.Error = {System.Security.SecurityException ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass5.

Any intelligent master coders out there who can solve this in their sleep?

Thanks if you can help.

Comment: Can you post the solution used ? ( The implementation of WCF service )

Comment: Well it would do no point since wow no longer exposes their data via an XML service.  Shame - it was a great set of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED - used a WCF service to act as a proxy due to cross domain security and header modification restrictions.  Thanks for all the advice.

Comment: FYI - WoW now exposes a rest based service so my question and any answers are out of date. The data is returned as JSON.  I think you get so many API calls, then you'll maybe want to ask them for extra permission to make large application calls.

Answer (score 3):

When running a Silverlight application in a browser, the silverlight application may only make requests to URLs from the same domain as the application was installed from.  For instance, if your silverlight app is installed from `http://yoursite.com/yourapp.xap`, you can only make WebClient requests to other URLs on `http://yoursite.com/`.  Your options here are either create a proxy script that requests the WoW armory from your server, and have your silverlight app hit that proxy, or run the silverlight out-of-browser and request full trust.

Edit: Generally the best option is a cross-domain policy file as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495868/error-accessing-rss-feed-from-silverlight-with-webclient).  Sadly, It does not appear that wowarmory.com implements the cross-domain policy file.

Comment: Sounds good in theory but this code was adapted from Scott Gu's blog, see http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-3-using-networking-to-retrieve-data-and-populate-a-datagrid.aspx

This example clearly uses digg server on another server.  Can you explain your comment compared with this seemly contradictory example?

Many thanks!

Comment: Digg implements a cross-domain policy file for silverlight.  Wowarmory.com doesn't :(

Comment: Nice to know that about digg :)

Answer (score 1):

you were on the right track, you just need to set the user-agent.

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string url = @"http://eu.wowarmory.com/guild-info.xml?r=Eonar&n=Gifted and Talented"; 
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();

        // HOW DO I ADD A USER AGENT STRING (RESPONSE MAY VARY (I.E. HTML VS XML) IF PAGE THINKS CALL IS NOT CAPABABLE OF SUPPORTING XML TRANSFORMATIONS) 
        //wc.ResponseHeaders["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)";

        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)";
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));    
    }

    void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            string result = e.Result;

            XDocument ArmouryXML = XDocument.Parse(result);

            ShowGuildies(ArmouryXML);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Something is complaining about security but not sure what!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: ooooo - so that's how you set the user agent string in .net 4.0.

Can't wait to try it - I will definately let you know how it turns out!

Comment: I get an error message stating that the user agent can't be modified directly...
+  InnerException {System.ArgumentException: The 'User-Agent' header cannot be modified directly.
Parameter name: name
   at System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.ThrowOnRestrictedHeader(String name, String value)
   at System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.Add(String name, String value)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.set_Headers(WebHeaderCollection value)
   at System.Net.WebClient.CopyHeadersTo(WebRequest request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebRequest(Uri address)
....

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize this is a silverlight application.

Comment: Last night I tried it in WPF - your code works a treat there and the whole application works as intended but for some reason I can't understand, it doesn't work in Silverlight.

Comment: SOLVED - used a WCF service to act as a proxy due to cross domain security and header modification restrictions.  Thanks for all the advice.